# Area of a circumscribed triangle

Tags: geometry

$AB$ is a chord of the circle and CD is the bisector of $\angle C,\ $CE = 4$\;\ and\;\ $ED = 6.

[image]

How do I find the area of triangle ABC?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that $AB$ need not be a diameter. See the following:
[image]

It is likely that the area may depend on the angle at $C$ and may not be uniquely determined by the given information.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm pretty sure that AB being a diameter was omitted by mistake from the question, because the answer is 24, and that is only possible with AB as diameter.

Answer (score 0):

A few hints:

$\angle CEB+\angle CEA = 180$

$\angle AEC+ \angle ACE+ \angle CAE = 180$

$\angle EBC+ \angle ECB+ \angle CEB = 180$

$\angle ACE+ \angle ECB=\angle ACB$

$\angle ACE=\angle ECB$

$\angle ABC+ \angle ACB+ \angle BAC = 180$

$AE*EB=4*6=24$ by the chord-chord theorem.

Comment: I don't get it. What can I do with all those angles? Some of those equations are linearly dependant, so I can't really get a concrete value for the angles. Also I don't see any triangle similarity. I'm really confused.

Comment: You could try to do something like law of sines. Also, this problem is greatly simplified if $AB$ is a diameter.

Comment: Given the answer, I'm pretty sure AB is a diameter. I know how to solve it if AB is a diameter, but I don't know how to prove that AB is a diameter.